# How to show code coverage feature in Chrome/Canary Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Was reading [using the chrome dev tools new code coverage feature](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-the-chrome-devtools-new-code-coverage-feature-ca96c3dddcaf?gi=7f170034d198) and was having trouble trying to enable this feature.

I know that Canary enables this without the need to unflag, but I'm unsure where to locate this feature from within Chrome Devtools.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With the developer tools window open, you can open the command menu using Cmd+Shift+P (Mac) or Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows, Linux), start typing **Coverage** and then select **Show Coverage**:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also select the three dots on the far right of the developer tools window, select **More Tools** and then select **Coverage**:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: click the more options dots]

It wasn't mentioned in the above post, but if you click the three dots in Chrome dev tools, the option for code coverage is shown in the menu.