# I cannot open the coverage tab in console in firefox dev tool

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo, webdeploy

Firstly I 'm  at beginning level in web development .I 've recently read that **delete unused css and other data** can improve my site performance so I opted to deal with it. From  [this](https://web.dev/unused-css-rules/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown)  article  I was directed to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference#coverage) where is described how to open coverage tab .

However after opening console on my site [(picture how it looks like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmbqA.png)when  I press **ctrl + shift + p** popped up [this private mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zA3n.png). Also when I tried to get to it by **3 dots** i can't find option like more tools (likely it was showed in [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394650/how-to-show-code-coverage-feature-in-chrome-canary-dev-tools)).

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Firefox, not Chrome, the website you got the CTRL + Shift + P from was Chrome DevTools, you're using Firefox, to open the Browser Console on Firefox, press CRTL + Shift + J.

Comment: I tried it but when I open browser console  I can't open coverage tab by clicking clicking ctrl + shift + p or by searching it. If you know other way to view used and unused CSS, you can tell me.

Comment: It’s CRTL + Shift + J not CRL + Shift + P

Comment: Man after I clicked ctrl shift J opens console browser . At that moment ** I want to get to coverage** tab so after again clicking ctrl shift j nothing appears. Furthermore I tried (after opening console browser) to click ctrl shift p and it also doesn't show me coverage tab.

Comment: It looks like Firefox doesn’t have a Coverage Tab, it’s exclusive to Microsoft Edge apparently.